# Laravel Login page not showing layout theme

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I created a project based on this tutorial https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-8-multi-auth-authentication-tutorialexample.html
But, in my login page not showing any theme, just showing plain html page
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3Lba.png)
how to fix this problem? thanks in advance

Comment: Add the relevant css files.

Comment: i think you need to check your css file location.....make sure that they match in your project folder....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have run `npm install` & `npm run dev` or `npm run watch`?

if not, run it, basically your view is not getting required CSS file to style your page.

Comment: thanks, you right mate, when i was failed when running the command, and i've looking for the problem and yea, the problem is when npm install & npm run dev

Answer (score 0):

just follow the following steps to implement that:-

1 ) composer require laravel/ui.

2 ) php artisan ui vue --auth .

3 ) npm install .

4 ) npm run dev .

5 ) then check localhost:8000/login